# LINQ and optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, controllers

I'm designing a web service to be consumed by an MVC app (pretty simple stuff), but I need a single method in the web service that takes up to four optional parameters (i.e. catId, brandId, lowestPrice and highestPrice).

How do I write the Linq query so that it essentially executes

```
databaseObject.Products.Where(p=> (p.Category == ANY if catId==null, else catId))
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The parameters of the method could accept null values and the Where restriction could be evaluated for each not null parameter:

```
IQueryable<Product> q = databaseObject.Products;

if (catId != null)
{
    q = q.Where(p => p.Category == catId);
}
if (brandId != null)
{
    q = q.Where(p => p.Brand == brandId);
}
// etc. the other parameters

var result = q.ToList();
```

Comment: You should probably declare q as `IQueryable<Product>`, but other than that, this is the perfect solution.

Comment: Does this solution not mean that all products are downloaded from the server and then filtered on the client system though?

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten it is not neccesary.

Comment: @Will Whitehead it is not true if databaseObject.Products is IQueriable. Materialization of query will be when ToArray(), ToList(), First(), Single(), Any() or other method will be called

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov It may be necessary to declare q explicitly as `IQueryable<Product>` if `databaseObject.Products` is of a derived type such as `DbSet<Product>`, otherwise the assignment `q = q.Where(...)` will not compile.

Comment: @Kris Vandermotten You are right, q needs explicit declaration, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 16):

If this is Linq To SQL:

```
databaseObject.Products.Where(p=> (catId == null || p.Category == catId) );
```

Linq To SQL, efficiently writes the SQL sent to backend without a where clause if CatId is null. You can have multiple of these constructs, and only those with a nonNull value is included in the where construct.

Answer (score 10):

```
databaseObject.Products.Where(p=> ((catId==null) ||  (p.Category == catId)))
```

For your other 3 optional parameters, you can AND them in, doing your entire search in one linq statement.

Comment: CatId != null is redundant and not needed there. It would shortcut to first one if it wasn't null. What did you mean "Linq is an overkill in this case if catid == null ? Linq would efficently create an SQL with no where clause then).

Comment: This is not a good idea.  Martin's answer is much better.  This will generate one parameterized query regardless of if catId is null or not, which will then be sent off to the database.  The database will then generate a sub-optimal query plan (or worse, pick an optimal query plan for the parameters you gave it and then reuse the same query plan for all future queries).  Martin's answer will generate an optimal query plan for the actual parameters it is fed.

Comment: @Robert - it looks like your comment and Cetin's comment are in conflict?

Comment: @Joe @CetinBasoz is incorrect, at least with the current drivers.  It may not always be the case in the future, but that is where it stands today.  Here's a real example: `int? catid=null;
var result=Categories.Where(c=>c.id==1 || catid==null);` results in the following SQL: `DECLARE @p__linq__0 Int = null
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name]
    FROM [Categories] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[id] = 1 OR @p__linq__0 IS NULL`

Comment: @Robert before declaring others incorrect, try reading what they say, and try modelling what they says the correct way. Since when Linq To SQL is spitting out eSQL? My answer clearly starts with "If this is Linq To SQL".

Comment: @CetinBasoz I apologize for the confusion. I answered his comment which referred to your **comment** which did not make the distinction that you were referring to LINQ to SQL exclusively and I confess I rarely consider LINQ to SQL when answering LINQ questions as LINQ to SQL was depreciated over 7 years ago.  LINQ to SQL apparently did make that optimization, but LINQ over Entity Frameworks does not. I stand by my answer that Martin's answer is much better as it performs better in all cases and is more portable than the one you gave (which is identical to this one).

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int? categoryId)
{
    var result = databaseObject.Products.Where(product => ProductCategoryPredicate(product, categoryId)
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns true if the passed in categoryId is NULL
/// OR if it's not null, if the passed in categoryId matches that
/// of the passed in product
///
/// This method will get called once for each product returned from 
/// databaseObject.Products</summary>
bool ProductCategoryPredicate(Product product, int? categoryId)
{
    if (categoryId.HasValue)
    {
        return product.Category == categoryId.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This could/can be simplified into a single line LINQ statement (see below) but I've written it long-hand above for clarity:

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(int? categoryId)
{
    var result = databaseObject.Products.Where(product => !categoryId.HasValue || product.Category == categoryId.Value);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but surely the linq query is essentially saying "SELECT product WHERE CategoryID IS NULL OR CategoryID = [param value]"?

I was more hoping for "SELECT product WHERE CategoryID = [param value]" if a param value was actually passed in, or just to return all products irrespective of their categoryID if no param was passed.

Comment: Not quite, the categoryId that's being checked is the one that's passed in. The code is functionally equivalent to `SELECT * FROM products P WHERE ISNULL(@productId, P.CategoryId) = P.CategoryId`. The predicate in the second GetProducts method basically returns TRUE if the CategoryId parameter is NULL (!categoryId.HasValue), and if that evalulates to false (i.e. categoryId is NOT NULL) it then moves on to compare categoryId.Value to product.CategoryId to look for a match.

Comment: Won't you get an error that it doesn't know how to convert ProductCategoryPredicate to SQL?